# Firebase Database Error - Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Edit: Figured it out, check my posted answer if you're having similar issues.**

I know there are several questions about this issue, but none of their solutions are working for me.

In my model class I have made sure to use List instead of Arraylist to avoid Firebase issues, but am still getting this error. It's a lot of code but most questions ask for all the code so I'll post it all.

TemplateModelClass.java

```
//
```

I've used this basic model successfully many times. For the

```
HashMaps<String, List<String>>,
```

the String is an incremented Integer converted to String. The List's are just Strings in a List. Here's some sample JSON from Firebase:

```
 //
```

Formatted that as best as I could. If you need a picture of it let me know and I'll get a screenshot

And am getting this error, as stated in the title:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList
```

The most upvoted question about this seems to have something to do with a problem using an integer as a key, but I think I've avoided that by always using an integer converted to a string. It may be interpreting it strangely, so I'll try some more stuff in the meantime. Thanks for reading!

Comment: export json from firebase and post it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. If anyone reading this has this problem and are using incremented ints/longs/whatever that get converted to strings, you must add some characters to the converted int. Firebase apparently converts these keys back into non-Strings if it can be converted.

For example, if you do something like this:

```
int inc = 0;
inc++; // 1
map.put(String.valueOf(inc), someList);
```

Firebase interprets that key as 1 instead of "1".

So, to force Fb to intepret as a string, do something like this:

```
int inc = 0;
inc++; // 1
map.put(String.valueOf(inc) + "_key", someList);
```

And everything works out perfectly. Obviously if you also need to read those Strings back to ints, just split the string with "[_]" and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is that you are using a `List` instead of a `Map`. As your error said, while deserializing it is expectig a `Map` but is found an `ArrayList`.

So in order to solve this problem youd need to change all the lists in your model with maps like this:

```
private Map<String, Object> mMapOne;
```

After changing all those fileds like this, you need also to change your public `setters` and `getters`.

Hope it helps.