# RecyclerView Adapter Map instead of Arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Patient Model

```
public class PatientInformation {
private String Firstname, Lastname, Gender, Contact, Address;
private Map<String, String> Teeth;

public PatientInformation() {}

public PatientInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, String contact, String address, Map<String, String> teeth) {
    Firstname = firstName;
    Lastname = lastName;
    Gender = gender;
    Contact = contact;
    Address = address;
    Teeth = teeth;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return Firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
    Firstname = firstName;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return Lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastName) {
    Lastname = lastName;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    Gender = gender;
}

public String getContact() {
    return Contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    Contact = contact;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}

public Map<String, String> getTeeth() {
    return Teeth;
}

public void setTeeth(Map<String, String> teeth) {
    Teeth = teeth;
}
```

and and Adapter for my recyclerview here

```
public class PatientsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PatientsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<PatientInformation> patients;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public RelativeLayout patientRow;
    public TextView tvPatientName, tvPatientAddress, tvPatientContact;
    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        patientRow = v.findViewById(R.id.patientRow);
        tvPatientName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPatientName);
        tvPatientAddress = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPatientAddress);
        tvPatientContact = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPatientContact);
    }
}

public PatientsListAdapter(ArrayList<PatientInformation> patients) {
    this.patients = patients;
}

@Override
public PatientsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_patients_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PatientInformation patientInformation = patients.get(position);
    holder.tvPatientName.setText(patientInformation.getFirstname() + " " + patientInformation.getLastname());
    holder.tvPatientAddress.setText(patientInformation.getAddress());
    holder.tvPatientContact.setText(patientInformation.getContact());

    holder.patientRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent patientInformationActivity = new Intent(context, PatientInformationActivity.class);

            patientInformationActivity.putExtra("PATIENT_FIRST_NAME", patientInformation.getFirstname());
            patientInformationActivity.putExtra("PATIENT_LAST_NAME", patientInformation.getLastname());
            patientInformationActivity.putExtra("PATIENT_CONTACT", patientInformation.getContact());
            patientInformationActivity.putExtra("PATIENT_ADDRESS", patientInformation.getAddress());

            context.startActivity(patientInformationActivity);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return patients.size();
}
```

and my insert function is here

```
.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                    String Firstname = etFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Lastname = etLastName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Gender = spinnerGender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                    String Contact = etContact.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Address = etAddress.getText().toString().trim();

                    Map<String, String> Teeth = new HashMap<>();

                    for (int x = 1; x <=32; x++) {
                        Teeth.put(String.valueOf(x), "Normal");
                    }

                    PatientInformation patientInformation = new PatientInformation(Firstname, Lastname, Gender, Contact, Address, Teeth);
                    databaseReference.child("Patients").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().setValue(patientInformation);

                }
            })
```

But I get an error when I run the app:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

I believe the error is on the adapter, because Im using an `Arraylist` instead of a `Map`. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Hum maybe the error is about the functions to get and set teeth for the patient because their you return and set a Map. Just to test try to not use them to see if you have the same error ?

Comment: Try this `Teeth.put("tooth_" + String.valueOf(x) , "Normal");` instead as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032887/firebase-database-error-expected-a-map-while-deserializing-but-got-a-class-ja).

Comment: @Journey Wow, that helped. Thanks bro!